# Run command on specific types of files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, file-type

I'm currently trying to run a program on certain types of files. Below is my batch script to do the following:

1. Clear a text file called "Projections.txt"
2. Loop through all the files in the current directory
3. If the file type .prj is found run the program gdalsrsinfo.exe and write it to a text file

Code is here:

```
break>projections.txt
for %%a in (*) do (
if exist *.prj (
echo ".prj file found"
echo %%a >> projections.txt
"C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalsrsinfo.exe" -e proj4 %%a >> projections.txt
)
)
```

I can't seem to run the program on just the .prj files, it's putting every file in the directory through "gdalsrsinfo.exe".

My question is how do I run "gdalsrsinfo.exe" on just .prj files.

Thanks

Comment: `for %%a in (*.prj) do (` and did you read the error on your unnecessary and wrongly used `if exist line`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your current code.

```
@echo off
break>projections.txt
for %%a in (*) do (
   if "%%~xa" == ".prj" (
       echo ".prj file found"
       echo %%a >> projections.txt
       "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalsrsinfo.exe" -e proj4 %%a >>projections.txt
   )
)
```

If however it is just `.prj` files you are interested in and not any other file you can explicitly filter for it in the for loop and eliminate the `if exist` part.

```
@echo off
break>projections.txt
for %%a in (*.prj) do (
       echo ".prj file found"
       echo %%a >> projections.txt
       "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalsrsinfo.exe" -e proj4 %%a >>projections.txt
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

The following methodology would be quicker and more efficient.

```
@(For %%G In ("*.prj")Do @(Echo ".prj file found">CON
        Echo %%G
        "%ProgramFiles%\GDAL\gdalsrsinfo.exe" -e proj4 %%G 
   ))>"projections.txt"
```

It is quicker and more efficient because it does not create an output file, then open, write and close it twice for every `.prj` file found.

In a more simplified format:

```bat
@Echo Off
(
    For %%G In ("*.prj") Do (
        Echo ".prj file found">CON
        Echo %%G
        "%ProgramFiles%\GDAL\gdalsrsinfo.exe" -e proj4 %%G 
    )
)>"projections.txt"
```

Comment: I think the author has answered the question - While your answer is more efficient and elegant it's harder to follow for a beginner.

Comment: @GarthCooper, I have added a couple of line breaks and explicit `@Echo Off` to make it look simpler for beginners.